# Hibernate: получение значений таблицы через третью таблицу

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc

Добрый день.
Есть три таблицы: "cars", "details" и "detail_car". У каждой таблицы есть id, у "detail_car" еще колонки car_id и detail_id. 
Т.е. cars и details объединяются через таблицу "detail_car".
Вот класс Car:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CARS")
public class Car {
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(
        name = "detail_car",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "car_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "detail_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
  private List<Detail> details;
}
```

При этом в консоли сервера выводится

```
    SELECT
    this_.id AS id1_0_2_,
    this_.about AS about2_0_2_,
    this_.img_url AS img_url3_0_2_,
    this_.mark_id AS mark_id6_0_2_,
    this_.model_id AS model_id7_0_2_,
    this_.NICK AS NICK4_0_2_,
    this_.year AS year5_0_2_,
    mark2_.id AS id1_4_0_,
    mark2_.MARK AS MARK2_4_0_,
    model3_.id AS id1_5_1_,
    model3_.MODEL AS MODEL2_5_1_ 
FROM
    CARS this_ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Marks mark2_ 
        ON this_.mark_id=mark2_.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Models model3_ 
        ON this_.model_id=model3_.id 
WHERE
    this_.id=?
```

Выпадает ошибка: Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.

Как в моделе Car получить список details, принадлежащий именно этой машине?

Comment: Ну вот же, вы их уже получили `private List<Detail> details` точнее вы их объявили и связали с таблицей а `Hibernate`, если все правильно, сам заполнит переменную `details` данными. Останется только добавить геттеры и сеттеры

Comment: В каком месте падает ошибка? пример кода?

Comment: Дебагером объект Car проверяю, все поля есть (в классе и гетеры, и сеттеры есть на все поля таблицы). Пытаюсь заглянуть в значения details, а там Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.

Comment: Используйте структуру `Hibernate.initialize(details)` перед тем как будете использовать список деталей

Comment: В контроллере прописал так:
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/show-{id}-car" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showCat(@PathVariable int id, ModelMap model) {
        Car car = carService.getCar(id);
        List <Detail> details = car.getDetails();
        Hibernate.initialize(details);
        model.addAttribute("car", car);
        return "showCar";
    }
выпало HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session

Comment: Добавьте перед методом или же всем контроллером(не помню уже) аннотацию `@Transactional`. И пожалуйста оформляйте все ваши комментарии как дополнение к основному вопросу сохраняя оформление

Comment: Cпасибо большое!     @Transactional сработал ( и без Hibernate.initialize(details))